# Configuring SQL Server Security for .NET Applications Without Profiler

Tags: profiler, sql-server-2008r2-express

How can I do this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815154 with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express because it seems to only apply to the higher versions of SQL. I know there are third-party profilers, but is there a way to do it without a profiler, and if I have to use a third party profiler. How would I do it with a third party profiler?

P.S. I need this so I can fix an ASP.NET problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preference is to go into IIS and create a custom AppPool with an Identity of a new user ("[productName]Website".  Then simply allow that user access in the Sql Server & Database(s) with the appropriate access (datareader/datawriter + grant on stored procedures).

[Application Pool Identities](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/)